# How to handle &apos; in XML with nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I am generating a XML file with the following the key/values using nokogiri XML builder.

```
<customize>
  <key>[@email=&apos;enter_your_email&apos;]</key>
  <string>foo@gmail.com</string>
</customize>
```

1.When viewing the generated XML file in browser, it doesn't show `&apos;` as ' in browser, it just shows  as `<key>[@email=&apos;enter_your_email&apos;]</key>`

2.when viewing generated the XML file as text, it shows

```
<key>[@email=&amp;apos;enter_your_email&amp;apos;]</key>
```

Is there any way to remove the amp; when generating XML file? Help me to solve this.

```
    build = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
      xml.customize {
          xml.key{ |x| x.text "[@email=&apos;enter_your_email&apos;]"}
          xml.string{ |x| x.text "foo@gmail.com"} 
          }
    end
    build.to_xml
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure if this helps.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.new
doc.encoding = 'UTF-8'

puts doc.fragment("<customize>
   <key>[@email=&apos;enter_your_email&apos;]</key>
   <string>foo@gmail.com</string>
 </customize>")

 #=> <customize>
  <key>[@email='enter_your_email']</key>
  <string>foo@gmail.com</string>
</customize>
```